# Quartz 2.2.1 + Spring 4.3.8

Tags: spring, quartz

It's some hours that I'm banging my head over this issue.
I have a Spring web application (with Jersey+Jackson REST API) and I'm trying to add scheduled jobs management with Quartz, which I had previous experience with.

Everything is fine, I've properly setup Quartz into Spring (using beans to wire jobs, triggers) and added this to my web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Now, if I call any service, a Spring Context gets initialized and the QuartzScheduled starts.
Problem is, I'd like to have the QuartzScheduler started at application startup, not when a Context is created.
This is crucial because for example the application (the server actually) is restarted nightly, and the scheduler must be started indipendently.

How can I achieve this, while also have such scheduler wired in Spring context for later use? It's been hours but haven't found a solution to this yet.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you creating a context when a request comes in? That already smell fishy. You should have a `ContextLoaderListener` that loads the context at startup and not load a context for each request.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah, I worded my question poorly.
Of course beans get initialized once on the first request and then kept for later use, and this is totally happening (my Scheduler is started and all the Jobs get executed).

Fact is, I need to initialize the context once, and this happens with first request, not at application startup...
Maybe that's something related to Spring configuration?

Comment: As stated that is strange as you should have a `ContextLoaderListener` that starts your context at startup. Why on earth would you do it on the first request...

Comment: Well, I've followed Spring documentation to set it up.
My beans (like transaction manager and the new QuartzScheduler) get instantiantiated only after the first request is made, not before. It's not something I've set up on purpose.
I guess I can force such initialization on application startup? I've tried already the ContextLoaderListener (binding it in web.xml) but it doesn't get fired at application startup at all...
I've put it here:
<web-app>
...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>it.dw.spring.CustomContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
    </listener>
...

Comment: Why the `CustomContextLoaderListener`? The listeners are loaded at startup so something must be delaying the default starting of the context (or you must be doing things completely differently).

Comment: I think you pointed me in the right direction. I had such CustomContextLoaderListener in my web.xml but is not fired on startup. I have to check why. I'll get back if I find something. Thanks for now!